# How to get Ubuntu distribution's full code name?

Tags: command-line, release-management

```
$ lsb_release -c
Codename:   trusty

$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS \n \l

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

Output's of the above commands shows only the partial code name (ie, `trusty`). How do I get the full codename (**trusty tahr**) of my installed Ubuntu system?

Comment: It seems that there's a convergent process towards the _sourcing_ of the file `/etc/os-release`. Maybe you should specify what you mean by _How do I get the full codename(trusty tahr) of my installed Ubuntu system?_. Do you only want to echo it on the terminal, or do you need it assigned to a variable? Is this going to be used on some non-{Ubuntu,Debian} systems?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using no external tools:

You can just *source* (the source command is a dot `.`) the `/etc/os-release` and you'll have access to all the variables defined there:

```
$ . /etc/os-release
$ echo "$VERSION"
14.04, Trusty Tahr
```

---

**Edit.** If you want to remove the `14.04,` part (as asked by terdon), you could:

```
$ . /etc/os-release
$ read _ UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME <<< "$VERSION"
$ echo "$UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME"
Trusty Tahr
```

Note that this is a bit clunky, since on other distributions, the `VERSION` field can have different format. E.g., on my debian,

```
$ . /etc/os-release
$ read _ UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME <<< "$VERSION"
$ echo "$UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME"
(wheezy)
```

Then, you could imagine something like this (in a script):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -r /etc/os-release ]]; then
    . /etc/os-release
    if [[ $ID = ubuntu ]]; then
        read _ UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME <<< "$VERSION"
        echo "Running Ubuntu $UBUNTU_VERSION_NAME"
    else
        echo "Not running an Ubuntu distribution. ID=$ID, VERSION=$VERSION"
    fi
else
    echo "Not running a distribution with /etc/os-release available"
fi
```

Comment: (echo _is_ builtin) but OK, how about this: `. /etc/os-release && echo ${VERSION//[0-9,. ]/ }` ?

Comment: @terdon there's more than one way to skin a cat `;D`.

Comment: What happened to all the comments here?

Comment: There are many and yours is a particularly good one! Comments that are irrelevant to the actual answer can be deleted without warning.

Comment: the embedded variable and value in os-release currently is defined to something like this:
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

Answer (score 10):

My variant on what's already offered:

```
. /etc/os-release; echo ${VERSION/*, /}
```

The shortest, Bashiest answer to date.

If you don't care to load `/etc/os-release`'s contents into your current environment, you can fake bash into thinking it's loading a script fairly easily:

```
bash <(cat /etc/os-release; echo 'echo ${VERSION/*, /}')
```

Comment: How dare you say _bashier than anything else to date_? there are other full bash answers here `:D`.

Comment: Why the downvote? it's a good answer (though with nothing conceptually different from others given before it).

Comment: Heh, clever use of process substitution, +1.

Comment: as one would expect from the master @terdon :)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I really meant *in combination* with its length though I'm not sure there's a shorter external way either. But yes, I clearly annoyed some people in the process :)

Comment: A simple subshell would do the job as well: `( . /etc/os-release && echo ${VERSION/*, /} )`.

Answer (score 8):

### Grep:

```
$ grep $(lsb_release -rs) /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info | grep -m 1 "Description: Ubuntu " | cut -d "'" -f2
Trusty Tahr
```

#### Explanation:

- `lsb_release -rs` -> Prints your installed Ubuntu version.
- `grep $(lsb_release -rs) /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info` -> Grab all the lines which contains your release version, in my case it's 14.04.
- `grep -m 1 "Description: Ubuntu "` -> Again grabs only the matched first line(because of `-m` flag) which contains the string `Description: Ubuntu`.
- `cut -d "'" -f2` -> prints the field number 2 according to the delimiter single quote `'`

### Awk:

```
$ awk -v var=$(lsb_release -rs) '$3~var {print $4" "$5;exit;}' /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info | cut -d"'" -f2
Trusty Tahr
```

#### Explanation:

Declaring and assigning Variable in awk is done through `-v` parameter.So the value of `lsb_release -rs`  command is assigned to the variable `var` which inturn helps to print  field 4 ,field 5 from the lines contain the string `14.04` and exists if its found an one.Finally the `cut` command helps to remove the single quotes.

Comment: it seems your solutions are based upon some python module for apt. that would mean a dependency on the file location and also on its formatting. also it only works if lsb_release with those options does provide a string that will match for the initial search operation. - nevertheless pointing out to those second source(!) to let others know about can in some special case be worth a million.

Comment: the grep variant might be able to be coded even shorter (with maybe a slight deviation on the exact search term - might not have practical relevance) - try this one:
grep -m 1 "Description: Ubuntu `lsb_release -rs`" /usr/share/python-apt/templates/Ubuntu.info | cut -d \' -f 2

Comment: oops, left-ticked quotes vanished as mini-Markdown syntax understood these as code highlighting request. you will have to undo this for the proposal to work.

Answer (score 7):

Answer relevant for at least ubuntu 16.04 and above:

```
lsb_release -cs
```

If for some reason `lsb_release` is not available

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep UBUNTU_CODENAME | cut -d = -f 2
```

Comment: even if i see some sympathy to your second way of parsing (instead of sourcing) the file in question - neither of the two options returns the full code name - only the first half is retrieved. xenial instead of xenial xerus, bionic instead of bionic beaver. sorry - that was not the question here.

Answer (score 4):

The command you are looking for is:

```
grep -oP '(?<=VERSION\=\"(\d\d)\.(\d\d)\,\ )(.*?)(?="$)' /etc/os-release
```

This is **very ugly** and not optimized. I'm sure there should be an easier method and this has some issues.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more choices. They all parse the `/etc/os-release` file which, on my 13.10, looks like this:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.10, Saucy Salamander"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 13.10"
VERSION_ID="13.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

All of the solutions below will parse the second line to produce `Saucy Salamander`.

1. `grep`

   ```
   grep -oP 'VERSION=.* \K\w* \w*' /etc/os-release
   ```

   The `-o` means "print only the matching part of the line" and the `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. This lets us use `\K` which discards whatever was matched up to that point, which combined with `-o` means "print only what matches *after* the `\K`. So, the actual regular expression used will match the last two words of a line that contains `VERSION=`.
2. `awk`

   ```
   awk -F'[" ]' '/VERSION=/{print $3,$4}'  /etc/os-release
   ```

   Setting the fields separator to `"` and `space` means that the 3d and 4rth fields of the line containing `VERSION=` are the string we're after.
3. `sed`

   ```
   sed -nr '/VERSION=/{s/.* (\w* \w*)"/\1/;p}' /etc/os-release
   ```

   The `-n` switch suppresses normal output, no lines will be printed. The `-r` allows extended regular expressions. Then, on lines that match `VERSION=`, we will delete everything except the last two words. The `p` at the end means print.
4. `perl`

   ```
   perl -lne '/VERSION=.*\b(\w+ \w+)/ && print $1' /etc/os-release
   ```

   The `-n` means 'process every input line with the script given by `-e`". The `-l` adds a newline character to every print call (and some other stuff which is not relevevant here). The regular expression matches the last two words (`\b` is a word boundary) and prints them if the line contains `VERSION=`.
5. coreutils

   ```
   grep VERSION= /etc/os-release | cut -d ' ' -f 2-  | tr -d '"'
   ```

   Here, we just `grep` the relevant line and use `cut` setting the field separator to `space` (`-d ' '`) and printing everything from the 2nd field to the end of the line. The `tr -d` command will delete the `"` from the end.
6. Pure shell (shamelessly stealing @gniourf_gniourf's clever `source` idea):

   ```
   . /etc/os-release && echo ${VERSION//[0-9,. ]/ }
   ```

   The `.` sources the file which makes the variables available to the shell and I use bash's [string manipulation capabilities](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to remove the version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
. /etc/os-release 
echo $VERSION
```

Comment: You still need to remove the numbers, see @gniourf_gniourf's answer below that uses exactly the same approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you could do this:

```
grep 'VERSION' /etc/os-release | grep -oP "[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+"
```

#### Explanation:

This searches the line with `VERSION` in the file `/etc/os-release`.
Then it finds 2 successive words seperated by a space (Perl regex).
The -o flag keeps only what matches the search.

You have to use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `w` to avoid including digits.

Answer (score 0):

I favor the delimiter-splitting `awk` variant:

`awk -F "[()]" '/VERSION=/ {print $2}' /etc/os-release`

The distro itself is retrievable via `/usr/bin/lsb_release -sd`.