# What is "deb deb-src stable/xenial main" in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, repository, software-sources

I was going through `Repository files` and in file **`/etc/apt/sources.list`**, saw these lines :

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial main
```

Wherein, I understand that

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu
```

is where apt-get would retrieve files from, but I couldn't get what the rest of words in it mean. These words are `deb`, `deb-src`, `xenial main`, `stable main`, `trusty main`.

**Edit:** Also, I found these lines while visiting [this site](https://winaero.com/blog/install-google-chrome-linux-mint-18/) and noticed **`[arch=amd64]`** in between `deb` and the URL.

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome.list
```

So, The Question here is:

- What do these words in `sources.list` file mean?

  ```
  deb
  deb-src
  xenial main
  stable main
  trusty main
  ```
- Also, What does **`[arch=amd64]`** mean?

Comment: See [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them?s=3|0.0000) and [How to get Ubuntu distribution's full code name? ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450298/how-to-get-ubuntu-distributions-full-code-name?s=17|0.0000)

Comment: This is not what I asked, please see C0deDaedalus answer and especially the comment he made below his answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question revolves around the syntax or format of source list file that describes other programs what, how & from where to get the sources. So, Here it goes :

#### [Apt ( `A`dvanced `p`ackage `t`ool )](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt)

used to manage the repository on Debian & Debian-based (Ubuntu) systems. It uses  a file that lists the `Repository Sources` from where packages should and can be obtained. Also the file lists how the packages should be obtained and from what subpackages (or suites).

---

## Everything lies in the [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)

The format in which entities are written tells everything to apt. However, there are two variations of the format.

1. **[One-line-style format](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#ONE-LINE-STYLE_FORMAT)**

   - They have extensions `.list`
   - Traditional format, supported by `all version of apt`.
   - A single line entry describes the source.
   - Example :

     ```
     deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main contrib non-free
     ```
2. **[deb822-style format](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#DEB822-STYLE_FORMAT)**

   - They have extension `.sources`
   - Supported by apt itself `since version 1.1`
   - Individual entries are separated by an empty line where each entry contains information in the form of `fieldname : value`.
   - Example :

     ```
     Types: deb
     URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
     Suites: stretch
     Components: main contrib non-free
     ```

As you can get an idea from `deb822-style format` what are those words you asked in question. Let's get into more details into **the format.**

#### 1. [Archive Type](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#THE_DEB_AND_DEB-SRC_TYPES:_GENERAL_FORMAT)

- It tells which source is going to be accessed.
- The first word on each line possibly `deb` or `deb-src`, indicates the type of archive.
- **`deb`** indicates that archive contains binary packages (deb), the pre-compiled packages that we normally use.
- **`deb-src`** indicates source packages, which are the original program sources plus the `Debian control files (.dsc)` and the diff.gz containing the changes needed for packaging the program.
- Format, syntax and names of the options vary between one-line-style and deb822-style formats as described above, but they both have the same options available.

#### 2. [Repository URL or URI Specification](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#URI_SPECIFICATION)

Its simply a URL/URI to the source repository from where you want to get the packages. You can specify type for the URL/URI that can be anyone from the currently recognized URIs that are :

```
http | https | file | cdrom | ftp | copy | rsh,ssh
```

You can add more recognizable URI types, If you want.

#### 3. Suite

A suite refers to combination of two attributes of distribution that are :

1. **Release Code Name**

   An alias given to every release of OS. Every OS has got a [Code Name](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DevelopmentCodeNames)
   & you already now that [How to get distribution's full code name ?](https://askubuntu.com/a/450520/769206)
2. **Release Class**

   Defines the development phase of a package that can be one or the combination of the following :

   ```
   stable testing unstable
   ```

#### 4. Components

Components tell that whether package is :

- Free (As defined in context of free software) or Non-Free,
- Independent ( as in `main` ) or have dependencies somewhere else ( as in `contrib` ).
- whether they comply with [DFSG](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines) or not.
- Also tell the [Repository Sections](https://askubuntu.com/a/58365/769206) that can be `main` or `restricted` or `universe` or `multiverse`.

#### 5. [Options](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#THE_DEB_AND_DEB-SRC_TYPES:_OPTIONS)

The **`EDIT part`** in your question refers to what is called as options. And as the name says, they are optional but when used, they modify the source entry to fetch a particular kind of packages. They can define :

- Architecture for which packages are to be fetched. As in options in the source entry you quote in Edit part :

  ```
  "[arch=amd64]"
  ```
- specific Language
- Trust level of sources
- Pdiff values
- and many others.

#### The Syntax (Revised) :

- **One-line-style format**

  ```
  [archive-type] [ option1=value1,option2=value2 ] URI suite [component1] [component2] [...]
  ```
- **deb822-style format**

  ```
  Types: deb deb-src
  URIs: uri
  Suites: suite
  Components: [component1] [component2] [...]
  option1: value1
  option2: value2
  ```

---

#### Some Useful Links.

1. [Example lines in sources.list file](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/apt/sources.list.5.en.html#EXAMPLES)
2. [How do I remove a malformed line in my sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78951/how-do-i-remove-a-malformed-line-from-my-sources-list)

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: @LinuxNewbie, Your question is marked as  duplicate of question that nowhere answers what you are asking for. You want to know **what each and every word in the sources.list mean** and **NOT** about ppas.

Comment: C0deDaedalus, I have edited my original post to tell that it is not a duplicate. Please see my edit 2 in bold..

Comment: Thanks again. You edited my question well. Now it makes more sense.